# fatal error: opening dependency file /main.cpp.o.d: Permission denied

Tags: compiling

Completely new to Ubuntu and programming as well. Installed CodeLite yesterday and still cannot compile a project. I get this after pressing "Compile this file".

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j4 -e -f  "ge_me.mk"  MakeIntermediateDirs && /usr/bin/make -j4 -e -f  "ge_me.mk"  /main.cpp.o'
----------Building project:[ ge_me - Debug ] (Single File Build)----------
<built-in>: fatal error: opening dependency file /main.cpp.o.d: Permission denied
compilation terminated.
ge_me.mk:97: recipe for target '/main.cpp.o.d' failed
make: *** [/main.cpp.o.d] Error 1
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Searched lots of problems about this throughout the internet, installed a number of packages. Since I wasn't understanding what I was doing (I am completely new to this stuff as I mentioned) I have run into this problem. Help please.

Comment: Where exactly is "this file" located? based on the message about `/main.cpp.o`, it looks like you are trying to save and compile files in the filesystem root directory `/` (rather than somewhere under your user's home directory - which is where you should be working).

Comment: @steeldriver, It is located in the project directory in the CodeLite workspace. I understood what you mean, how can I specify compiling file path then?

Comment: Perhaps you have misconfigured your project's "Intermediate Directory" setting? See for example [Project Settings](https://wiki.codelite.org/pmwiki.php/Main/ProjectSettings)

Comment: @steeldriver, thank you a lot for your help. But it seems that I have not any C++ compiler...
I don't know if GCC is a C++ compiler

Comment: `g++` is the GNU C++ compiler

Comment: @steeldriver, now I know the problem. I have been receiving "There's new version of CodeLite available" messages and decided to update it. However, I don't have any CodeLite apps in Ubuntu Service Center. Haven't found anything in the internet about it...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem some minutes ago; I solved by setting the intermediate directory settings into `$(ProjectPath)/Temp`, as suggested by @steeldriver in the comments.